# How to mask a particular word in a sentence if the word exists in the sentence in c#

Tags: c#, string

I have a string like `The Password for the website is money`, now if the string contains the word `"money"`then i have to mask the string like `The Password for the website is XXXXX`. The substitute `XXXXX` length should change based on the length of `money` i.e, if the string is `The Password for the website is moneyyyyy` then my output should be `The Password for the website is XXXXXXXXX`

### so far i tried like this

```
string content="The Password for the website is money";
string pattern = @"\bmoney\b";
string replace = "XXXXX";
content = Regex.Replace(content, pattern, replace);
```

---

But no result i even tried with string replace instead of regex but no use.
Please help me out with this.

Comment: Interesting that you want to mask a word "money" which is not in the need of protection in general. Instead you should mask what follows the phrase "password for ... is...". What if someone changes the word password to something else? Then it's not masked anymore.

Comment: If you just want to replace a exact occurence, use `String.Replace` instead of Regex

Comment: Is it always the last word in the expression?

Comment: @stuartd no it is not the last word in the sentence it may be any where

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a match evaluator with `Regex.Replace` and the regex to match any word with a key inside, like `\w*money\w*`:

```
var content="The Password for the website is money and moneyyyy";
var key = "money";
var pattern = string.Format(@"\w*{0}\w*", Regex.Escape(key));
var mask = 'X';
content = Regex.Replace(content, pattern, m => new string(mask, m.Value.Length));
Console.WriteLine(content);
// => The Password for the website is XXXXX and XXXXXXXX
```

See the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/TZi3tU)

The regex means:

- `\w*` - zero or more (`*` is a quantifier that matches zero or more instances of the quantified subpattern) word chars (letters, digits and `_` symbol). NOTE you may tune this part to only match letters if you replace it with `\p{L}*` (or if you only need ASCII, use `[a-zA-Z]*`.
- `money` - the `key`, you might need to `Regex.Escape` it if there are special symbols inside
- `\w*`  - see above.

Comment: Thank you so much it just worked like a charm for me

Comment: @Meena: Great, I  added the regex explanation to the answer with hints on how to adjust it if need be.

Comment: what to do if i have special character and digit  in money i.e, mo@123ney ? please let me know..

Comment: Not a problem here. It will still work as expected. Unless you want to find `mo@123ney` with just `123`. Then it won't work, you'd need something like `@"\S*{0}\S*"`.

Comment: What is not working? Post the search key string, the input string, and expected result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137758/discussion-between-meena-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: But it is not working if my word starts with $ can anyone help me out

Comment: Do you mean a "WORD" can contain *any symbols other than whitespace*? Then replace `\w` with `\S`. See my previous comments: *`@"\S*{0}\S*"`*

Comment: i tried with @"\S*{0}\S*" but it is not working . this word is not masking $mo@123ney.

Comment: It does, have a look [at this demo](http://ideone.com/I6n7Sf). From now on, let's provide demo links in the comments and indicate what is wrong. As for me, the `var key = "$mo@123ney";` works well with `var content="The Password for the website is money $mo@123ney and moneyyyy";` if `string.Format(@"\w*{0}\w*", Regex.Escape(key))` pattern is used.

Answer (score 1):

Warning! OP added later that the password wasn't at the end of the string. My answer will work only in this case. Feel free top go on :)

---

Something like this?

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sFYHfQ) on .Net Fiddle.

```
    var k = "The Password for the website is money";
    // we remove the noise
    var password = k.Replace("The Password for the website is ", "");

    // we add the noise and we use a string constructor to duplicate the letter.
    Console.WriteLine("The Password for the website is " + new string('X', password.Length));
```

output:

```
The Password for the website is XXXXX
```

Comment: According to OP, the password is not always the last word, so this won't work

Comment: @Pikoh Thank you. I added a warning. :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume only `password` part in your text changes

```
string content = "The Password for the website is monafsfasdey";
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"\bis\b\s(.*?)$");
var match = pattern.Match(content);
if (match.Success)
{
    string replace = new string( 'X', match.Groups[1].Value.Length);
    content = pattern.Replace(content, replace);
}
```